# System Calls Function for prompting and getting user input

Tags: c, user-input, system-calls

Ok, so I am writing a C program for my class, but I am only allowed to use system calls. Basically our program is making our on     cp command, where we are taking two files as inputs from the command line and copying the first file and putting it into a second file. It is relatively simple and I have most of the code right or just about right with maybe some small fixes. However, one part of the program is if the destination file already exits, we need to prompt the user to ask if it should be overwritten or not, so I need to know how to get user input using a system call function, aka I can't use scanf, fgets, gets etc. The only function I can use from the standard library is printf basically. So I need to know what the system calls function is to get a user prompt. This part of the code is suppose to work like     cp -i , if that helps anyone. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use system call `read`. To read from standard input, `fd` (file descriptor) is 0.

`$ man read`

> READ(2)
>
> Linux Programmer's Manual (2)
>
> NAME
>
> ```
>    read - read from a file descriptor
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <unistd.h>
>
>    ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.
>
>    If count is zero, read() returns zero and has no other results.  If count is greater than SSIZE_MAX, the result is unspecified.
> ```